# XPath Ancestor Issue

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the `<SubdivisionName>` ancestor for the `<Spec>` node. I can get it for the first  (result "AAA"), but all other imported records have the same result ("AAA") when the next should have a result of "DDD". If anyone can spot my error, I would appreciate any help. I have tried a multitude of variations of the XPath, but either get the same result or no result at all. Thank you in advance.

Sample XML:

```
    <Corporation>
    <Builder>
        <BuilderWebsite>...</BuilderWebsite>
        <Subdivision>
            <SubdivisionName>AAA</SubdivisionName>
            <Plan>
                <PlanName>BBB</PlanName>
                <Spec>CCC</Spec>
            </Plan>
        </Subdivision>
        <Subdivision>
            <SubdivisionName>DDD</SubdivisionName>
            <Plan>
                <PlanName>EEE</PlanName>
                <Spec>FFF</Spec>
            </Plan>
        </Subdivision>
    </Builder>
</Corporation>
```

The XPath I am currently using is
`//Spec/ancestor::Subdivision/SubdivisionName`

The full function I am using is:

```
<?php

function wpai_pmxi_before_xml_import( $importID ) {

    // Retrieve import object.
    $import = new PMXI_Import_Record();
    $import->getById( $importID );

    // Ensure import object is valid.
    if ( ! $import->isEmpty() ) {

        // Retrieve history file object.
        $history_file = new PMXI_File_Record();
        $history_file->getBy( 'import_id', $importID );

        // Ensure history file object is valid.
        if ( ! $history_file->isEmpty() ) {

            // Retrieve import file path.
            $file_to_import = wp_all_import_get_absolute_path( $history_file->path );

            // Load import file as SimpleXml.
            $file = simplexml_load_file( $file_to_import );

            // Check if Status is a child of Procurement.
            $query = $file->xpath( "//Spec/ancestor::Subdivision/SubdivisionName" );

            // Ensure value isn't empty.
            if ( ! empty( $query ) ) {

                // Value of status as string.
                $status = $query[0]->__toString();

                // Target path.
                $new_query = $file->xpath( "//Builders/Corporation/Builder/Subdivision/Plan/Spec" );

                // Ensure path is valid.
                if ( ! empty( $new_query ) ) {

                    // Process each Procurement element.
                    foreach ( $new_query as $record ) {

                        // Ensure this element doesn't have SubdivisionName.
                        if ( ! isset( $record->SubdivisionName ) ) {

                        // Add {SubdivisionName[1]} as child node.
                        $record->addChild( 'SubdivisionName', $status );

                        }
                    }

                    // Save updated file.
                    $updated_file = $file->asXML( $file_to_import );

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pmxi_before_xml_import', 'wpai_pmxi_before_xml_import', 10, 1 );

?>
```

Comment: Everything else aside, I can't replicate the problem with your sample xml; `$query` returns "AAA" and "DDD".

Answer (score 1):

`SubdivisionName` is not an ancestor of `Spec`.  An ancestor is a parent or a parent's parent, recursively.  `SubdivisionName` is only an aunt/uncle of `Spec`, not an ancestor.

Moreover, it's easier to simply add a predicate on `Subdivision` to target the desired `SubdivisionName` without transcending up from `Spec` anyway:

```
//Subdivision[Plan/Spec="AAA"]/SubdivisionName
```